# Most Overpowered Supporting Cohort - Crafter or Buff-Station?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, followers-and-hirelings

Up until recently, I lived under impression that there is no better use of Leadership than personal crafting station, AKA Artificer. Effectively crafting everything at 1/4th of the price (28.12%) is something that skews the power progression very much in PC favor.

But since I started playing my God-Wizard archetype, double-progression support caster, I started realizing how powerful 24-hours-long buffs can be, especially when the pool of those buffs is "all spells in the game". With those buffs my current PC is immune to pretty much everything, is pretty much impossible to hit and has higher weak-save than most well-optimized characters can say about their strong one. The one thing it can't do is win on its own. This is a support caster, through and through. There simply aren't enough feats and class features left to invest in anything battle-ready.

But what if this very same character (give or take small details) was a cohort? What if instead of 4 times the value of magic items in my possession I would have a private buff-station, heal-station, dispel-station, all happening from either safety of Gate Rings or sitting in a Portable Hole (tiny warforged or what-not so breathing is not an issue).

So this is my question: **pure numbers, optimization-wise, what is a stronger choice for a cohort between the two: a crafter for 4 x magic items value or aaforementioned support caster?**

To be more specific:

- By **Buff-Station Cohort** I mean a double-progression caster with free Persistent Metamagic (several ways to do it, for the sake of this topic not important which one) that can keep all the best buffs in the game permanently active on PC. Access to healing, debuff-removal and escape from critical situations all included.
- By **Crafter Cohort** I mean a pure-crafting-specced Artificer that creates all Magic Items in 28.12% GP price, 2.25% XP price and 0.75% crafting time in days. What we're getting here is effectively level 15 gear value at level 10. Another good comparison would be having as much gear value as rest of the team combined.
- I did consider other options but those two are so far above the rest that there's no point in mentioning them.

We're assuming player is the one making his Cohort from scratch, having 100% control over it, as if it was his PC. 100% official content allowed (books, erratas, wotc web enhancements, etc.). Campaign levels 1 to infinity. Everything RAW, including things like GP / level table. As much downtime as players need.

I wanted to keep the question as generic as possible but since big picture thinking doesn't work on SE, let's focus specifically on a PC that is a Fighter-based melee combatant. Goal is to make the character as strong as possible, both damage-wise and defenses-wise. Attack bonus and damage as high as possible; AC, Saves, Resistances as high as possible, as many Immunities as possible, as much mobility as possible, etc.

Also, please don't mention anything that benefits the team. We're maximizing a single PC here, team has nothing to do with that.

DISCLAIMER: (I forgot to add it before, I usually do) No pun-puns, no infinite loops, nothing that defies the purpose of playing the game in the first place.

Examples of what I consider completely natural (unlike Pun-Pun, Infinite Wishes and mechanical loops):

- Using Eyes of Truth to persist True Seeing without component cost of a spell.
- Using Thought Bottle to effectively have double the amount of spells to cast daily.
- Having persistent Freedom of Movement, Polymorph (because that's the best way to get +bajilion Natural Armor), Veoil of Undeath and many others cream-of-the-crop buffs that were never planned as something to be active 24/7.

Comment: I can input more details if that helps, just tell me what kind of details. This is purely mathematical question (biggest numbers how? A or B?) so there is absolutely nothing opinion-based here.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit to include OP's constraints. There really isn't a good reason to make them submit the same question with the constraints they wanted. Yes, in a perfect world, we'd have figured out constraints before answer so as not to invalidate, but in this case the best path for OP to get an answer that is what they are looking for is to update with the disclaimer.

Comment: This question should be closed because 1. it is an optimization request without specifying what is being optimized, just seeking the “best” cohort without defining what that means, 2. even taking the false dichotomy that it presents as a constraint on answers, the “two” options are extremely broad archetypes—there are hundreds of variables in each that might affect how well it functions as a cohort, and 3. the fundamental reality here is that the answer is necessarily always contextual, on the leader, the party, the campaign. This is as unanswerable as “which is better, cleric or wizard?”

Comment: Here are some questions that I think would make this answerable.  What level?  What gp?  What books allowed?  How much downtime is allowed?  Do the other party members have any useful abilities?  What items are you considering for crafting?  What buff spells are you considering for your buff cohort?

Comment: (I agree that the question as currently written is much much too broad, because answering it requires identifying which magic items should be crafted and which spells should be made persistent, across a large number of sourcebooks.  And we don't even know what level the cohort is!)

Comment: Also, what level of cheese is allowed? OP is assuming their DM will allow them to take the Leadership feat and build their own custom cohort and keep the cohort in a portable hole. Are our answers allowed to assume similar exploits?

Comment: @DanB Exactly—without all kinds of information about the leader, the party, the campaign, the levels, the sources, the houserules, completely and entirely defining exactly what is or isn’t allowed, and defining exactly what is or isn’t valuable, and how to evaluate them, _this isn’t a question_, it’s a discussion prompt.

Comment: @DanB Those are not exploits, just standard optimization strategy. GM's right to make decisions ends on the edge of PC character sheet. I answered most of Your other questions and added to OP. Other party members doesn't matter, we're talking about something that by definition is supposed to make everyone else feel useless (unless they optimize to such degree themselves).

Comment: @DanB As for "considered spells" that's part of the answer not the question. Select spells for buffs, select items for craft, prove what results in better numbers and why.

Comment: @NecXelos: who creates and controls the cohort are unclear from a RAW perspective. It's generally the case that the player has a great deal of control over both aspects of the cohort they attract, but the rules seem to imply that the GM should create and control them - they're NPCs, after all (with their own character sheets; the PC's character sheet only includes the word "Leadership"). Assuming that one's cohort is happy to live in a portable hole except the 5 minutes a day it takes to buff or hand off crafted goods sure feels like an exploit to this GM.

Comment: [Meta discussion on this question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12047/4563)

Comment: Well, I have some ideas in mind, but unfortunately your most recent edit still leaves me confused about whether any of them would be considered acceptable (or whether you'd just edit your question to rule them out).  I suspect that you won't accept any answer that doesn't explicitly list "optimal" choices for magic items and persisted spells.  That's way too much work for me; I suspect it's too much work for anyone.

Answer (score 6):

There is, of course, an enormous problem with your question: you ask for the “most overpowered cohort,” and then ask “crafter or buff station,” as if these were the only two options. That is a false dichotomy.

Firstly,

### Pun-pun

Pun-pun can be a cohort as easily as he can be an independent character. In terms of what a cohort can do for you, Pun-pun trivially tops the list, because Pun-pun can do anything. Anything any other build might have to offer, Pun-pun can also offer, and more. Depending on how you read *manipulate form*, Pun-pun may well be able to offer things that are not available any other way.

Pun-pun is, in short, both a crafter ***and*** a buff-station, and also anything and everything else.

And that’s instructive because

### Por que no los dos?

Artificer is convenient for crafting. It’s hardly *required* for crafting. It gets way more item-creation feats than you really need—Scribe Scroll, Brew Potion, Craft Wand, Craft Rod, Craft Staff, and Forge Ring are all pretty questionable feats. Five of them just let you cast spells you probably could cast anyway. Forge Ring only produces rings, which you can only use two of at a time. None of them is a *bad* feat—well, Brew Potion might be—but compared to Craft Wondrous Item and Craft Magic Arms & Armor, they’re not even playing in the same league. 90% of all magic items are wondrous items, and your weapons and armor are the most expensive items most characters own. After Craft Wondrous Item and Craft Magic Arms & Armor, what you really want are the Exceptional/Extraordinary/Legendary/Magical Artisan feats to cut down on crafting costs. That’s at *most* 7 feats (assuming Magical Artisan for both Craft Wondrous Arms and Craft Magic Arms & Armor), which is a lot, but...

Casting buff spells doesn’t really require feats, and wizards get bonus feats that can include those item-creation feats, or those metamagic feats that a buffer does want: Extend Spell and Persist Spell, plus some way of cheesing Persist—illumians can get it 2/day without even spending a feat, just by using *Naenhoon*. And then maybe Combat Casting to qualify for spellguard of Silverymoon,¹ and/or Iron Will for incantatrix to get more spells persisted. The other major prestige option here—rainbow servant—doesn’t require anything.

So even if you aren’t Pun-pun... why limit yourself to just one or the other? Sure, an artificer could be a better crafter. And maybe there are some other feats you might want to get as a buffer. But the low-hanging fruit of each can go farther than either one.

### But—Pun-pun aside—it *is* very contextual

So I’m going to call our options the crafter, the buffer, or the ¾-of-each character I’m describing above. In a vacuum, ¾crafter+¾buffer in a sense is 1½ of what the other options are (not that these numbers are remotely scientific). But what if your party already has an artificer? Now having some of the same feats they do, and the ability to make some of the same items they can—but possibly without quite the same discounts—is worth *way* less. Now you’d much rather your cohort be devoted to just buffing. Or vice versa: if you have a stellar buffer in the party, now having an artificer cohort sounds a lot better. Or *what if* your party already has both? Maybe now you want a bard, just for something different that will stack with those. (Maybe we should have considered a bard/sublime chord to begin with?)

And on, and on, and on. This is, of course, ignoring everything about your actual character, as well, and everything about the campaign. There are literally-infinite variables here, and any one of them could completely change the answer to this question.

**Pun-pun is the only possible definitive answer to this question. Any other suggestion for a universal answer is simply incorrect, and that will never change. You cannot receive the answer you are looking for because that answer does not exist and never will.**

1. <sub>Assuming a DM who is willing to either waive or work with you on the spellguard’s obligations, and willing to expand the notion of “defensive” spells.</sub>

Comment: I mentioned buffer as "24-hours buffs". This means quite a restricting build and Artificer will never be able to fill both purposes. On top of that best buffs are above level 4 spells which is also a hard deal for Artificer. I also mentioned artificer being the only class able to handle 1/4 casting price on every craft, but that eats up pretty much all feats available to him, feats that other classes don't get. This also answers Your other concerns, since no buffer in the party will have enough to give me all the 24-hour-long buffs I need. We're maximizing my character, not entire group.

Comment: @NecXelos If you have “very specific builds” in mind, _post them_. Don’t allude to specific characters you’ve played before and then pretend the rest of the Internet is going to automatically know all of their details.

Comment: @NecXelos Please add those kind of restraints or conditions to the question. Try to put as much information as you can into the question rather than making answerers guess at the details.

Comment: Big edit added to the question. Should be as precise as possible now.

Comment: @NecXelos Not even remotely sufficient for me to look at that and say “oh yeah, that definitely means you can’t do both.”

Comment: @KRyan Than feel free to provide an answer describing a build that can both craft all the items at % of the price I mentioned and provide all the high-end buffs of both classes. And please refrain from giving me Scrolls Example. Those are one-use items that add up to infinite amount of money when used every day in the morning for buffing.

Comment: @NecXelos No, my point is _no one but you knows the details of the builds you have in mind._ Which means we have no idea what restrictions those requirements actually place on the character. This has—predictably—become “what’s the most overpowered cohort (that doesn’t break my personal limits on broken content, which I’ll amend as I see fit)” which is, again, unanswerable. This is my answer. If you change the question sufficiently that it no longer is the answer I think best to the question, I’ll delete it. You won’t get another.

Comment: PunPun is the ultimate solution to anything anyway. They're a God at 1st level.

Comment: @Trish Yes, that’s the point: this question is no more answerable than “what’s the most overpowered character?” Only a character who can literally do anything and everything can be a definitive answer to that. Otherwise it’s all context and preference.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sorcerer vs. wizard dichotomy, re-phrased.

A buffer is a sorcerer in this metaphor: they do what they do well, and have an edge against a random monster today. But, they can "only" do what they can do.

A crafter is a wizard: they can do anything the sorcerer can do and more, but might need to wait 'til tomorrow to do it.

The crafting subsystem includes guidelines for turning any spell into a continuous magic item: any buff that the buffer can provide today could be provided by a magic item tomorrow. The question is which one is better in "this" campaign or scenario.

... and, yes, on how generous the GM is with crafting custom magic items. There are guidelines for putting spells into cans, but there is no rule that says "any spell can be made into a use-activated or continuous item". And, of course, the GM would need to allow merging items and/or converting slotted items into slotless items (here I picture characters walking around with dozens of ioun stones orbiting their head). Of course, staves are a thing.

... and, of course, on how much treasure the party finds and whether crafting requires rare reagents that may require their own quests. If you never find any treasure, crafting becomes difficult.

So, which is better? That depends on how much time you have to answer the question.

Comment: Nothing about this answer is true or have any support in rules. There are no "rare reagents", You just pay the cost, fulfill requirements and item is crafted. There are tables for how much "value" players are supposed to have at each given level. GM has nothing to say about merging items, there are tables describing crafting costs for slotted, slotless or multiple-effect items. It's all pure math, nothing else. Everything You mentions are house-rules and we're not discussing house-rules but actual rules.

Comment: @NecXelos: there are guidelines about pricing non-standard magic items and how much wealth players should have, but no rules about either. There are high- and low-treasure campaigns that are totally RAW, and there are campaigns in which only standard magic items can be produced which are, again, totally RAW. There are also no rules that state it's just GP + XP + time; the GP cost is for "Magic supplies", which may or may not be readily available wherever the PCs find themselves (just like magic items generally, specific items, or even mundane items).

Comment: This is all fluff, not system rules. As far as rules go gold and supplies/materials/reagents are all and the same. You throw money, stuff spawns from mid-air. Everything else is storytelling, which has nothing to do with rules. If GM uses storytelling excuses to gatekeep player options - don't play with this GM. Not to mention crafting happens in downtime anyway so my average response to "you can't find materials here" kind of passive-aggressive GM is "ok, we'll just refuse to do anything for 10 years, travelling around the world until we find what we need for crafting".

Comment: @NecXelos: we cannot say "the highest ref save you can get at level X is Y". Pun-pun proves that: he can always increase his ref save. If you exclude him, the line that does so affects how high you can pump your ref save, but there isn't an obvious bright line to use. Ditto any other character aspect. Thus, general principles must be found, which should be widely applicable. The general principle here is: if the GM is generous with crafting and time, it will win.

Comment: @NecXelos:  There's no rule that says you can make an at-will item of Magic Missile (or Miracle!), or that crafting just requires GP. The _guidelines_ provide an estimated GP cost, but they aren't "this is what crafting costs" rules, they're "this is where to start when pricing a new magic item" guidelines. Outside of the published magic items, there's no rule that says "anything goes" or that any spell or effect must be craftable. Similarly, no rule says that vorpal swords must be available for purchase, even though they have an easily-calculable price. ... or that downtime is available.

Comment: @NecXelos The Variant: New Magic Items says, "In the same way that you can invent new spells and monsters for your campaign, you can invent new magic items. In the same way that a PC spellcaster can research a new spell, a PC may be able to invent a new kind of magic item" (*DMG* 214). Nobody likes this rule, but RAW is that *only* published magic items (and spells and monsters) exist, and new things can't be created *at all.* It's a variant—optional—rule that new magic items and spells can be created at all then to make them requires the DM's largess.